# Android N, O App Overlay stays after Permission request declined

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo, android-7.0-nougat

I have an app that needs access to the users accounts.
As the user declines the Contact Permission Dialog, the odd behaviour begins.

As usual the dialog appears and the app in background gets an overlay to darken content. If the user declines the permission now, the **dialog disappears, but the darkening overlay stays** (it also prohibits user-interaction).
The content visible behind overlay is changed accordingly to the declined permission. 
The Error occurs only on devices with Android N and Android O, M looks perfectly after declining and lower api levels do not have runtime permissions, so they are doing their job as well.

A few stats:

- minSdk 16
- compileSdk 27
- targetSdk 27
- Buildtools Version 27.0.3
- supportLib 27.1.1
- com.google.android.gms.auth 15.0.1

Also there are other permission requests, which are working just as they should (e.g. Location).
Only the dialog shown for GET_ACCOUNTS (Contact permission Group) does not handle the overlay right.

It would be awesome, if somebody could give me some hints, which dependencies may exist that I did not see.
Thanks a lot in advance to everybody reading this, giving my problem a few thoughts, sharing a similar story even without a solution. Every hint or input will be appreciated :D

**Update:**

I removed the permission dialog and present the accountChooser to the user, but the misbehaviour stays. The only difference is, that even after choosing an account (and so granting the permission for this account) the overlay stays. As in background the app is visible, I can verify the features functionality and online data is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lengthy search it appered not to be a problem with the permission dialog or the account chooser, but with the underlying progressDialog, which got activated by a button press.
The by now deprecated progressDialog was started and the background was greyed and inactive. Now two formally suspected dialogs kicked in. After their confirmation they got hidden correctly. The inactive grey overlay was part of the old progress dialog.
I am sure the error was due to a timing problem while hiding the progressDialog which got interrupted by the two system dialogs.

The solution for me was to scrap the old progressDialog and build a replacement (custom alertdialog), which is shown and cancelled in separate threads. The custom Dialog hides now as it should and even the grey overlay disappears properly.

Thanks everyone, I hope this may help others finding their solution faster ;)